# Getting prime numbers as shown the first func uses the second one

Tags: javascript

How does this work? Can you please explain step by step?

```js
// function to show primes

function showPrimes(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
    console.log(i); // a prime
  }
}
// function to check prime
function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// trigger to run the function and put the value of (n)

showPrimes(10);
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: how it works !! step by step i cant understand the logic !

Comment: You need to learn the basics of JavaScript syntax. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+syntax

Comment: If you don't know anything about javascript. You should first do a tutorial (such as this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm. there are thousands online) and then if there's still something you don't understand, try to make a more specific question. people in this site expects you to do some research on your own before asking.

Comment: thank you i will first learn the basics

Comment: i dont really like this method of finding primes; however, one thing you may want to change.  your **for** loop where you are checking the modulo. you would never need to go further than **halfway** to **n**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isPrime` is the function which takes a number and return `true` if number is prime otherwise `false`.

**How `isPrime()` works:**

> A prime number is a number which is divisible by any number other than `0` and number it self

Or in other words a number which is divisible by any number between `1` and the number it self is not prime.

```
for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) //creates a loop with 2 to n-1.
if ( n % i == 0) return false;  //checks if that number is divisible by 'i'. If it is it return false
```

If `false` is not returned inside the loop it means the number `n` is not divisible by any number from `2` to `n-1`. So after the loop `true` returned

**How `showPrimes` works:**:

`showPrimes()` takes parameter `n` which is limit to which primes numbers will be shown.

```
for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) //creates a loop from 2 to n-1
```

The next line checks if the number is not prime. If its not prime then `continue;`

```
if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
```

> The continue statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration

Or simply if the number `isPrime(i)` return `false` The loop will not go to the line

```
console.log(i);
```

And will go the to next number.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// function declaration
function showPrimes(n) {
  //For loop from first prime number to number of prime numbers to be printed (10)
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    // Condition to check if a number is prime or not
    if (!isPrime(i))
      continue; //if it is not prime, then loop will continue to next iteration
    console.log(i); // a prime will be shown
  }
}

// Function declaration
function isPrime(n) {
  //For loop to iterate till the given number that is to be checked for being prime or not
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    // If in any case the number is divisible by any number between 2 to n, then its not prime
    if (n % i == 0)
      return false; 
  }
  return true; // no need for an else after a return 
}

showPrimes(10); // execute
```